# ZF2 install via Composer getting wrong PHP version

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework2, composer-php

I have to install ZF2 on Windows:

1. I've clone ZendSkeletonApplication (ZSA) repository from Git
2. Open cmd and get in ZSA folder
3. run `php composer.phar self-update` (everything is ok)
4. run `php composer.phar install`

And now I get this:

> zendframework/zendframework 2.3.1 requires php >=**5.3.23** -> no matching package found.

Okay, I've checked php version `php -v`:

> PHP **5.3.6** (cli) (built: Mar 17 2011 10:37:07)

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you, guys. I was confused by 0.6 > 0.23 (didn't sleep for 2 days), next morning I realized my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZF 2.3.0 and above requires PHP 5.3.23 or above. You have 5.3.6 (6 is less than 23!). You either need to upgrade PHP to a more recent version, or downgrade to ZF 2.2.x.

Comment: Here is the conversation about this requirement: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/5602

Answer (score 0):

5.3.6 is less than 5.3.23. `>=` means "greather than or equal to".

Zend Framework 2 requires at least `5.3.23`, while you have `5.3.6`. That means your PHP version is not supported, you can't use the Zend Framework on that server.

What you can do:

- Update PHP version to something newer (5.3 is getting pretty old)
- If you are sure you already have a newer PHP version installed, check that the cmd is using the new PHP binary and not the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you update your local Windows version of PHP to the version you are using in production. If that production version is not able to run Zend Framework 2.3.1, you'd not benefit from solving the dependency problem you are experiencing.

Composer does not allow you to change the internally used PHP version if your local PHP is simply used to put together all dependencies but to used to execute these. So matching the production version is a good thing.